How to poll incoming kafka message into Flux
Currently working on a project using Spring Boot 3.2.7 with web Spring Cloud stream binders. I have a data layer which based on provider implementation is streaming some data into my service. Something along the lines of:
// Loader definition used in various services
public interface ILoaderSPI {

    Flux<MyData> load(DataRequest request);
}

// Example usage Rest Controller

@Autowired
private ILoaderSPI someLoaderImpl;

@PostMapping(consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(OK)
public Mono<ComputeResult> compute(@RequestBody @Valid ComputeSpec spec) {
    return Mono.just(spec)
               .flatMap(this::someServiceCall)
                // used as middleware to load some data externally
               .flatMapMany(data -> someLoaderImpl.load(data))
               .collectList()
               .flatMap(this::compute);
}

For now I have a single implementation which basically does an external client request.
public RestLoaderImpl implements ILoaderSPI {
    @Autowired private Webclient client;
    @Override
    public Flux<MyData> load(DataRequest request) {
        return client
                .post()
                .uri(...)
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .bodyValue(request)
                .retrieve()           
                .bodyToFlux(MyData.class);
    }
}

And now I have to add a new data provider which will be loaded using Kafka (send request for data on kafka/receive said data on kafka and convert it)
So far I have used different kafka consumers using the stream cloud bindings like so (but I am only triggering some event processing based on incoming messages)
public class SomeHandler implements Consumer<Flux<List<IncomingMessage>>> {

    @Override
    public void accept(Flux<List<IncomingMessage>> messages) {
        messages.flatMap(this::handleMessage)
            .subscribe();
    }

}

This subscription is done once and messages keep flowing.
Mock idea of consumer (Function should be subscribed to automatically) - declared input/output as Mono in the hopes that it resubscribes each time a message comes because I am only interested in streaming into my workflow a single event
public class KafkaLoader implements Function<Mono<DataRequest>, Mono<List<MyData>> {

    @Override
    public Mono<List<MyData>> apply(Mono<DataRequest> request) {
        request.flatMapMany(this::convertData).collectList();
    }

}

public KafkaLoaderImpl implements ILoaderSPI {
    @Autowired private final StreamBridge streamBridge;

    @Override
    public Flux<MyData> load(DataRequest request) {
        Mono.just(request)
            // request through kafka
            .doOnNext(request -> streamBridge.send("request-topic", request))
            // only care to receive the "next" incoming message and connect it here
            .then(somehow stream the data from the kafka consumer whenever it receives it);

    }
}


Is there a way to achieve this ?

I think the proper signature for the reactive function would be:
Function<Flux<DataRequest>, Flux<List<MyData>>

This way the framework would subscribe once for that input Flux.
Not sure if that is really supposed to be a Flux<List>, or you just can flat-map the data into a single Flux<MyData>.
The Cosnumer could be as simple as Consumer<IncomingMessage> in the end.
I don't see where is Apache Kafka related part in your question.

Hi, that is correct regarding the proper use of the signature. This will allow the framework to subscribe to the Flux and new messages will automatically be published. What I wanted was a way to connect this stream of data into a separate publisher which is part of a middle layer. What I think I'm going to do is simply push incoming data onto a concurrent map correlated with a unique request id and then in the middle layer take advantage of takeUntil operator to fetch it from the map as soon as it's available.

Sorry, I don't see the whole picture of your use-case, but perhaps something like Sinks.Many can help you to push data in the middle of the flow.
